# Custom Style.json and Vector tiles loading but sprites not appearing in Maputnik

Tags: symbology, style, mapbox, icon, maputnik

I have a custom tile server and custom sprites that I'm trying to add in Maputnik. I've added a symbol layer but I can't get the sprites to show up. I know the tiles are loading and working because if I display text ("x") in the symbol text it is showing up where it should be:

[image]

As far as I can tell the json and png are loading because they show up in inspector and when I open them they look right. Also, the dropdown for icons appears with all of the options in the json:

[image]

But nothing I do will make the icons appear. I've tried editing the paint and layout properties in all sorts of ways and trying different icons but still not getting anything. This is the json for the layer from Maputnik:

```
{
  "id": "service_layer",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "services",
  "source-layer": "service_pt_adultcare_2021",
  "layout": {
    "icon-ignore-placement": true,
    "icon-allow-overlap": true,
    "visibility": "visible",
    "icon-rotation-alignment": "auto",
    "icon-optional": false,
    "text-field": "x",
    "symbol-avoid-edges": false,
    "symbol-z-order": "auto",
    "symbol-placement": "point",
    "icon-size": 1,
    "icon-anchor": "center",
    "icon-image": "Congregate_Breakfast"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here - I forgot to include pixelRatio in the sprite.json. I guess I thought it was optional or just didn't notice it.

eg:

```
"Botanical_Garden": {
    "x": 257,
    "y": 0,
    **"pixelRatio": 1,**
    "width": 26,
    "height": 26
},
```